# How to make std::variant<..> available to QVariant?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to use `std::variant<Foo, Bar>` as internal value of `QVariant`. How to do this?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <variant>

enum Foo{A, B};
enum class Bar{C, D};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::variant<Foo, Bar>);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
error: macro "Q_DECLARE_METATYPE" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
 Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::variant<Foo, Bar>);
                                          ^
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt, but how about `using T = std::variant<Foo, Bar>;` and then `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(T)`?

Comment: variant with `using T = ...` compiled ok

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` is a macro, and macros don't like `,`s.

You can either pass a type alias

```
using T = std::variant<Foo, Bar>; 
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(T)
```

or wrap the use in extra `()`

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE((std::variant<Foo, Bar>));
```